# Selecting from a table, then calculating moving average and inserting a new record into table in one SQL sentence

Tags: sql, hana

What I need to do:

1. Select a record that matches parameters and is MAX(Date).
2. If that record exist, based on that record and a new record, calculate moving average and increase quantity.
3. Then insert the new record with quantity and moving average to the same table.

What I have so far is that I get the existing record, but I don't know how to do the calculations in SQL and how to insert the new record back.

```
SELECT "QuantitySum", "AverageUnitPrice" 
    FROM "minute.db.data::tables.MaterialLedger"
    WHERE "CreatedAt" = (
    SELECT MAX("CreatedAt")
    FROM "minute.db.data::tables.MaterialLedger"
    WHERE "CustomerId" = ${iCustomerId} AND "StorageLocationId" = ${oEntity.StorageLocationId} 
    AND "ProductId" = ${oEntity.ProductId} AND "CurrencyId" = ${oEntity.CurrencyId} 
    AND "ReservedProjectPhase" = ${oEntity.ReservedProjectPhase} AND "ReservedOrgUnit" = ${oEntity.ReservedOrgUnit})
    as CurrentLedger
    INSERT INTO "minute.db.data::tables.MaterialLedger" (${sColumns}) 
    VALUES ( ${oEntity.StorageLocationId},  ${oEntity.ProductId}, ${oEntity.Quantity}, ${oEntity.UnitPrice}, ${oEntity.UnitId}, ${oEntity.CurrencyId}, CurrentLedger.QuantitySum + ${oEntity.Quantity},  )`
```

It needs to be done in one SQL sentence.

Here is also the table I'm working with currently:

```
 entity MaterialLedger {
    key Id                         : Integer generated by default as identity(start with 1 increment by 1);
        ValidFrom                  : UTCTimestamp         not null;
        ValidTo                    : UTCTimestamp         not null;
        CreatedById                : String(100)          not null;
        CreatedAt                  : UTCTimestamp         not null;
        ChangedById                : String(100)          not null;
        CustomerId                 : Integer              not null;
        StorageLocationId          : Integer              not null;
        Date                       : UTCTimestamp         not null;
        ProductId                  : Integer              not null;
        Quantity                   : Double               not null;
        UnitPrice                  : Double               not null;
        UnitId                     : Integer              not null;
        CurrencyId                 : String(3)            not null;
        Value                      : Double               not null;
        QuantitySum                : Double               not null;
        AverageUnitPrice           : Double               not null;
}
```

Comment: Please [DO NOT post images](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.

Comment: I am not very professional at HANA Sql Script, but unlikely it is possible in one statement. You will need stored procedure or a function

Comment: It is certainly possible to do the three steps as a single SQL command. The more important question is, whether that can possibly be correct. Calculating the moving average (essentially an aggregation) and storing it at the same time requires to *lock the whole table for reads*. Otherwise, any statement running in parallel would have started to calculate the average without the new value currently being inserted. That's one of the reason for not storing aggregates directly in tables (besides, it violates all normal forms!).

Comment: @LarsBr. i also thought about storing the moving average in a separate table, but that presents even more problems and also requires locking the tables in question. do you have any pointers how the insert statement with the average calculations would look like ?

Comment: out of curiosity: why should the moving average be stored at all? It's not that expensive to calculate it at query time and storing it requires a lot fo effort to ensure consistency (what happens with updates/deletes?)